# how to check if a notification has been closed in javascript

Tags: javascript, notifications

I am having a problem with a notification not closing when the notification pops up and I close it when I refresh the page the notification comes up again so I want to check if they have clicked the close button on the notification

heres my code for the notification

```
<script>

        function notifyMe() {
          if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
          }
          else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            notify();
          }
          else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
              if (permission === "granted") {
                notify();
              }
            });
          }

          function notify() {
            var notification = new Notification('This months topic is stranger danger', {
              icon: 'assets/qr-codes/studentmeshCourseVideo.png',
              body: "this months topic is stranger danger click on me to a video that studentmesh has provided to educate your child about stranger danger or scan the qr code in shazam to get to the video",
            });

            notification.onclick = function () {
              window.open("assets/course-videos/strangerDanger.mp4");      
            };


          }

        }
        notifyMe();
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should store notification status in localstorage. When user click on close button you should write in localstorage for example: `localStorage.setItem('notification-closed',true)`

And when notify call check localstorage flag like this : `localStorage.getItem('notification-closed')`, if it true, doesn't show notification once again.

```
 function notifyMe() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('notification-closed')) {
           return;
      }

      if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
      }
      else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        notify();
      }
      else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
          if (permission === "granted") {
            notify();
          }
        });
      }

      function notify() {
        var notification = new Notification('This months topic is stranger danger', {
          icon: 'assets/qr-codes/studentmeshCourseVideo.png',
          body: "this months topic is stranger danger click on me to a video that studentmesh has provided to educate your child about stranger danger or scan the qr code in shazam to get to the video",
        });

        notification.onclick = function () {
          window.open("assets/course-videos/strangerDanger.mp4");      
        };


      }

    }
```